# Is there a way to control dry/wet balance of AKOperationEffect?

Tags: audiokit

In an attempt to smooth out crackling/zippering when changing parameters on an AKDelay, I switched to using AKOperationEffect. However, unlike AKDelay, AKOperationEffect has no dry/wet mix parameter. How do I change it?

Answer (score 1):

I wound up composing a wrapper class with an optional AKDryWetMixer node that I just use for cases where the effect needs an additional dry/wet mixer (as is the case with AKOperationEffect). Seems fine.

Obviously, if there's a "proper" solution, or something obvious I'm missing, I'd appreciate a heads-up.